# Spring Security PostAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, security, rest, spring-security

I'm trying to secure a REST web application with Spring Security 3.2 ( I use Jersey/Guice in addition to Sring Sec).
I successfully managed to use the authentication and role authorization, however I'm having a hard time making the @PostAuthorization annotation working on my methods.

Here is my spring security configuration :

```
<beans>
  <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="exampleExpressionHandler"/>
  </security:global-method-security>

  <bean id="exampleExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="myPermissionEvaluator"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="myPermissionEvaluator" class="org.test.spring.application.security.SecurityPermissionEvaluator" />

  <security:http auto-config='true' create-session='stateless' use-expressions="true" realm="My Webapp Backend">
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/v1/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_WEB_API')"/>
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="permitAll"/>
      <security:http-basic />
  </security:http>

  <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider>
      <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="webapi" password="webapi" authorities="ROLE_WEB_API" />
        <security:user name="webuser" password="webuser" authorities="ROLE_WEB_USER" />
      </security:user-service>
      </security:authentication-provider>
  </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Here is the implementation of the PermissionEvaluator (very simple should deny all) :

```
public class SecurityPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator
{
   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityPermissionEvaluator.class);

   @Override
   public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission)
   {
      logger.info("=YAH= Security Evaluator hasPermission() invoked");
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission)
   {
      logger.info("=YAH= Security Evaluator hasPermission2() invoked");
      return false;
   }

   public SecurityPermissionEvaluator()
   {
      logger.info("=YAH= Security Evaluator created");
   }
}
```

And finally here is the code I expect to trigger my permission evaluator

```
   @GET
   @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")
   public List<MyDTO> getHomePages()
   {
      return myDTOAssembler.toDTOList(hompepageRepo.findAll());
   }
```

When I access my ressource I never get any of the "=YAH=" log messages, seems that my evaluator never gets called nor created.

Also spring reports no errors when starting the app so no lead on that neither.

I'm pretty sure it is a configuration issue, but I really followed the guide and the SO q/a and could not come with something better.

So if you have any suggestion I'll be really greatfull, beacuse I'm really quite new to the Spring world.

Comment: How do you create the object that has the @PostFilter on it? That object either needs to be created by Spring so it can proxy it or you need to use AspectJ to compile it.

Comment: Well it turns out that I don't use neither Spring (other then security) neither AspectJ in my app. Does it mean that spring method level security cannot be used "out of the box", without all the spring framework ?

Comment: You need to create the aspects in one way or another. If you use Guice to create your objects, you should be able to create the aspects that intercept the methods but it will not be a trivial task since there is no DSL (i.e. `<global-method-security>`) to configure it.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Means that I have to go for the implementation of my own security filters for the method/service level. Pity but I was somehow expecting this to happen.